# How to convert a 5FPS video into a timelapse?

Tags: video, video-processing, frame-rate, timelapse

I have recorded a video at a constant frame rate of 5. I would like to speed this up to make it look like a timelapse without having it look choppy.

I have already tried speeding up the video by 2x, 4x, 8x etc and it doesn't have any effect on the choppiness of the video it just makes it quicker (obviously)

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Is this supposed to be a **programming** question or just in wrong forum? Use your same Stack account to ask at [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) or [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/). You can use free software like FFmpeg.

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video